# How to pass data from frame buffer object(FBO) back to JAVA?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am a newbie playing around with OpenGL ES on Android, what I have achieved are:

1. Use JNI call and write all OpenGL logic on CPP
2. Render an image and save in FBO(Magic!)

Since after step 2, texture should be stored in GPU memory, what I curious about is it possible to dig it out and read it back? Like pass whatever data in FBO back to JAVA side in RAM.

Comment: Either [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) or [`glMapBufferRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml)